# Android Webview scroll from scrollbar

Tags: android, webview, scroll, scrollbar

How to scroll the Android WebView with scrollbar while I am viewing PDFs with the help of URL.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have to add these pro[erty in your oncreate method                              
       webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
     webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I can not scroll the content of webview by dragging scrollbar.